# Is it possible to bookmark answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

If the answer is the most popular one then i can favourite the question. But ive seen a couple answers that were low on the list, slightly off-topic, etc , that id like to look into (or quote) at a later date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup. Just click the `link` button on the answer to get a 'unique' link for it. Then bookmark that page.
[image]